# How to refresh page on history.state change (on back button click)?

Tags: javascript, html, browser-history

I'm testing new JS/HTML5 `history` methods. On subpage load I have an event changing the URL and history state:

```
$("#content").load("./content/map.txt", function() {
     history.pushState({}, "map", "map.html" );
     window.history.go(1);
});
```

Now when the user clicks back button the `history.state` and the URL changes, **but** without loading the previous page (without refreshing the current URL).

I tried to add a manual refresh on the `history.state` change, I found something like this:

```
window.addEventListener('popstate', function(e){
     if (history.state){
         self.loadImage(e.state.path, e.state.note);
     }
}, false);
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: this doesn't have much to do with the history function but caching in the browser and how you handle it.  also use window.history.back, same thing.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
window.onpopstate = function(event) {
  if(event.state["map"] == "some_state") // get the current state from the event obj
    location.reload(); // reloads the current page to clear ajax changes
};
```

Comment: That goes against the whole idea of not having to reload a page.

Comment: Then he can do whatever he wants in the method instead of location.reload();. The point is this works for listening for a state change and getting the current state.